# Select from tables from 2 databases with Kohana Framework

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

For Example I've got 2 databases called: `Site_X` and `Site_Y`

`Site X` DB - Has the table `Data`

`Site Y` DB - Has the table `Data_ids`

How can I use kohana to get all the data from `Site X` DB that has id equal to what I find in `Site Y` DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define config for both DBs in config/database.php

Then you can do the following (replace site_y, site_x with config names for your databases):

```
$ids = Database::instance('site_y')
    ->query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT `id` FROM `Data_ids`')
    ->execute();
$results = Database::instance('site_x')
    ->query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT `id` FROM `Data` WHERE `id` IN ('.implode(",", $ids).')')
    ->execute();
```